# No DNS servers on Virtualbox instance of kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, dns

I have started a virtual machine running kali-rolling (2022.3)

I noticed that there are no DNS servers configured

```
┌──(root㉿kali)-[~]
└─#     cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search home
```

Why is that?

Since this is my first time using `kali`, my question is whether this is a `kali` trait of something related with my `linux` instance running from within `Virtualbox`.

Should I set the public DNS servers of Google to address this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, kali's mission statement is to not make any external communication without explicit configuration to do that, so that makes sense.

Also, as a pentesting tool, *not* using the nameserver one gets via DHCP automatically would make sense, as well. But since you did not mention you connected the VM through DHCP, this might not even be the case.

So, this seems pretty sane to me! Kali is a special-purpose tool. Don't expect defaults that would be sane for a Linux distro that is meant to be something that people use for *anything but penetration testing*.

If you really want a Linux distro with which you can surf, Kali probably isn't the right choice, says [Kali Linux themselves](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/).